# How to write the square root of a number in HTML?

Tags: html

How do you write the square root to a number in HTML? I am going through the W3 tutorial on HTML and nothing really gives me what I want, a square root which encloses the number, something like this image below:[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, its not elegant but it should work:

```html
<span>&#8730;</span><span  style="border-top: 1px solid black">x</span>
```

Comment: Is the # the square root?

Comment: @BBTanis it is the hook part of the square root, the border-top is the line over the x (Check this link: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/square-root/)